# Swift AdMob ad wrong size

Tags: swift, admob

I'm using AdMobs smart banner in may app, I did everything as suggest in Googles Getting Started except banner size isn't fixes `320x50`, its `screen widthx50`. In auto layout I added 1 constrain for horizontal center and 1 for screen width. If I run that on simulator I works great but on device I'm getting this error:

```
<Google> Unable to set adSize property. Not enough space to show ad with custom size, {600, 50}. Please use a size that fits the current screen bounds of {320, 568}.
<Google> To get test ads on this device, call: request.testDevices = @[ @"bb3f8f97887" ];
<Google> Unable to set adSize property. Not enough space to show ad with custom size, {600, 50}. Please use a size that fits the current screen bounds of {320, 568}.
<Google> Invalid Request. Ad size will not fit on screen
```

If I log GADBannerView view size I'm getting this (running on iPhone 5):

```
Size:  (0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 50.0)
```

This is my code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var bannerView: GADBannerView!

bannerView.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-394/216"
bannerView.adSize = kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait
bannerView.rootViewController = self
print("Size: ",bannerView.bounds)
bannerView.loadRequest(GADRequest())
```

These are my constrains

[image]

Comment: You don't have a constraint for the width.

Comment: Lol no problem. It's always the little things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a width constraint.

Ctrl-Drag from the AdView to the parent and select Equal Widths.

Answer (score 2):

for SwiftUI make sure to add frame of view

```
BannerAd(bannerID: "ca-app-pub")
                        .frame(width: 320, height: 50)
```